# Getting value for dynamic input of different types

Tags: jquery

I'm loading different types of input fields (textareas, radiobuttons, checkboxes) with ajax in my document.

```
var SugesstionValue = $('#EditModalAddSuggestionValue').val();
if(SugesstionValue === null || typeof SugesstionValue === 'undefined')
{SugesstionValue = $('#EditModalAddSuggestionRadioValue input:checked').val();}
alert(SugesstionValue);
```

I'm getting every time `undefined`
Sometimes it works and sometimes not... I'm not sure what to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on without more code. But based on your description, it sounds like you have a race condition because the code you provided is not being run *after* you load your fields via ajax. That's why `SuggestionValue` is sometimes `undefined` and sometimes not.

When you select something from the DOM, it has to actually be in the DOM at the time you try to select it. That means you have to select ajax-loaded elements *after* you load them. You could do that in your success callback, provided you add the fields to the DOM before doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that the value of the field was changed by a nother funktion and thats the reason why it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Just a small correction, this is not a race condition, but rather a failure to wait or check for the existence of a resource before acting on it. It's the same as not checking that a file exists before opening it, or not waiting for the DOM to be ready before trying to navigate it.